# Search-form action attribute with Advanced AJAX Page Loader wordpress plugin returns "more than one title tag on the page.." warning in debug mode

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search-form

I'm trying to enable search functionality of the Advanced AJAX Page Loader plugin on a custom wordpress theme I'm building, but after I enter keyword into search and hit enter, loader.gif keeps on spinning and I get this message in debug mode : "WARNING: You seem to have more than one title tag on the page, this is going to cause some major problems so page title changing is disabled". It also passes the url of the website twice into the address bar and I believe this has something to do with the action attribute that's being passed by the form.

This is the site in question: http://natalija.co.nf

I left the debug mode of the AAPL plugin on for now

This is my searchform.php code:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" class="btn" />
    <input type="text" size="10" name="s" id="s" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
</form>
```

I managed to ajaxify the theme with this plugin but I 'm having trouble getting the search to work properly so I was wondering if anyone here can help me out with this? It is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The code in search.php needs to be wrapped with a div class="searchform".